# Как определить с помощью JS, что браузер вывел все элементы

Tags: javascript, jquery

На страницу выводится большое количество строк. Браузер отображает какую-то часть, потом зависает и через некоторое время "раздупляется", отображая все остальное. Как с помощью JS можно определить момент "раздупления", т.е. что все элементы показаны (именно показаны) на странице, а не момент, когда DOM сформирован (использовал и window.onload, и document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ...)). Эти методы срабатывают сразу после окончания формирования DOM, но не после отображения всего содержимого

Comment: Боюсь, я не понял что такое "раздупляется" и как этому помочь.

Comment: Раздупляется - когда начинает реагировать на клики, различные манипуляции, т.к. в этот момент даже F12 не срабатывает

Comment: @Other это, наверное, доминошный термин - когда игрок в "козла" долго думает, а потом раздупляется - ходит дублем

Comment: @Other Наверное залагал а потом отлагал.

Comment: @IK Ну знаешь сейчас, когда браузер подгружает контент - это нормально, если он подвисает. Потому, что может ты не знал но div браузер подгружает по мере скролла страницы, в отличии от таблицы, которую браузер загружает всю и сразу.

Comment: что именно ты выводишь? сервер отдает готовую разметку? или ты потом дозапрашиваешь по ajax? или добавляешь в каком-нибудь цикле на клиенте сам?

Answer (score -1):

```
const a = Document.querySelectorAll('body');
console.log(a);
```